# How to changs voice? (Speech to speech)

Tags: natural-language-processing, deepfakes, speech-synthesis

How to change soms person voice to another person voice (speech to speech) in this way:

1. First we record our voice.
2. Then, record second person voice.
3. Change first voice to second voice. (I mean the output should have first voice sentences but with second person voice.

Comment: What are your findings so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.